# Can't add settings with User as scope in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

So I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC5 application on Visual Studio 2015 Community and decided to add some application settings. I do that using the designer at `Project Properties` and `Settings` tab.

The Scope is empty at first but it changes to `Application` **THE MOMENT** I click on it, and there is no way I can change it.

If I remember correctly, application scope could be set to `User` at previous versions of Visual Studio.

[image]

My application needs some options with R/W access. `Application` scope is read-only therefore is useless for my case.
How do I fix this?

Comment: `User` scope is not available in a web app (only desktop apps)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is there any way I can do similar thing without a database in web app?

Comment: Why not a database? You need to persist them somewhere but you could always use an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been stated, `user-scope` is not available in `IIS`.

You can try the following alternatives:

- [Linq to Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb)
- [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express)
- [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx)